# How to install adb on Ubuntu from download

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-installation, adb

I have a desktop computer running Ubuntu 16.04.  This computer does not have an internet connection (I am at work and this is not a work computer).  I have been able to use a Wifi tether app using my phone on a laptop running Ubuntu but I installed the required Google ADB library via wifi at home. I need to install ADB on this desktop.
I have downloaded a folder called platform_tools from Google that contains ADB but I do not know how to install this package from download as I am new to Linux.  There is nothing that appears to be an installer in this directory.
How do I install ADB from this download?

Answer (score 2):

Download the [`SDK Platform-Tools for Linux`](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html#download)

Then run:

```
unzip platform-tools-latest-linux.zip
cd platform-tools
mv adb /usr/bin/adb
```

Now run your `adb` commands e,g:

```
adb devices
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the folder you have downloaded actually contains a runnable `adb`.

```
cd /path/to/platform-tools
./adb devices
```

If your phone isn't connected you should just see a message where the list of attached devices is empty.
If the platform_tools folder that you have downloaded actually contains the `adb` binary then you just need to move it to some location of your choice then add it to your `PATH` so that the terminal can find it.

Simply run `mv /path/to/platform-tools /your/chosen/location` (likely you have the platform_tools folder in downloads, you *do not* want this in your PATH). Now add the following line to your `.bashrc`: `export PATH="/your/chosen/location/platform-tools:$PATH"`. Next time you open a terminal you should be able to run `adb` directly (or run `. ~/.bashrc` to force it).

Comment: The line you need to add to your bashrc is `export PATH="/home/gerry/platform-tools:$PATH"`. You are telling the shell which directory to look for `adb` in, not where the adb binary is explicitly.

Comment: (in response to your now deleted comment)